# .htaccess redirects and preserves the filename without file extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm redirecting but now I want to preserve the file name to resemble a directory.

I would add a query string with the name of the file to add it to the redirect URL but that doesn't make much sense.

e.g

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+profile\.php\?user=([^&]+)&uid=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Internal

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1&uid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

this redirects to www.site.com/username/uid

I want this to be www.site.com/profile/username/uid

I would add a third query string like www.site.com/profile.php?user=username&uid=45&profile but it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might slightly modify the rewrite rule.

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+profile\.php\?user=([^&]+)&uid=([^&\ ]+) 
  RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

And internally.

```
  RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1&uid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok that does it. You might wanna remove the asthmatic signs and only leave the correct code. Its confusing.

Comment: It’s very common diff signature to mark deleted/added lines of code. It helps 99 out of 100 visitors to understand what’s to be done with the code. Whether it confuses you, I have it removed.

Comment: Have never visited github? :)

Comment: I have only do download stuff.